# Creating two priority queues from the same struct with the opposite order

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, priority-queue

I have got this struct:

```
struct Passenger
{
unsigned arrive;
unsigned depart;
};
```

Now I need to create an A and a B priority_queue with the opposite order. If I overload the operator<, they will have the same order.

I would like to know, how could I create these priority queues with the oppositi comparator?

Comment: Do you want the ques to be independent or would the removal of a Passenger from one queue cause the removal of the same passenger from the other queue as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to specify the comparator when you create the priority queue:

```
// For the moment, I'm specifying these to just compare arrival times.
// Modify that as needed.
struct GT {
    bool operator()(Passenger const &a, Passenger const &b) { 
       return b.arrive < a.arrive;
    }
};

struct LT { 
    bool operator()(Passenger const &a, Passenger const &b) { 
        return a.arrive < b.arrive;
    }
};

std::priority_queue<Passenger, std::vector<Passenger>, GT> max_heap;

std::priority_queue<Passenger, std::vector<Passenger>, LT> min_heap;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a comparer for [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

```
typedef std::priority_queue<Passenger, std::vector<Passenger>> min_queue;
typedef std::priority_queue<Passenger, std::vector<Passenger>, std::greater<Passenger>> max_queue;
```

Or, generic:

```
template <typename T, typename Container = std::vector<T>>
using min_queue = std::priority_queue<T, Container>;

template <typename T, typename Container = std::vector<T>>
using max_queue = std::priority_queue<T, Container,
        std::greater<typename Container::value_type>>;
```

And then:

```
min_queue<Passenger> my_min_queue;
max_queue<Passenger> my_max_queue;
```

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to look into `boost::multi_index` then you can have one singe collection that can be accessed in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

`std::priority_queue` has a second and third template parameter:

- The second is the underlying container, it's default is `std::vector`
- The third is a comparator class like in `std::map` and `std::set`

**So you should *not* overload an `operator<`, because that would not be intuitive to use.** Instead, implement those comparators:

```
struct ArriveLess {
  bool operator()(Passenger const& lhs, Passenger const& rhs)
  { return lhs.arrive < rhs.arrive; }
};

struct DepartLess {
  bool operator()(Passenger const& lhs, Passenger const& rhs)
  { return lhs.depart < rhs.depart; }
};

/* ... */
std::priority_queue<Passenger, std::vector<Passenger>, ArriveLess> A;
std::priority_queue<Passenger, std::vector<Passenger>, std::not<ArriveLess>> B;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a "Compare" function to the priority queue template:

```
std::priority_queue<Passenger> A;
std::priority_queue<Passenger, std::vector<Passenger>, reverse_compare> B;

bool Passenger::reverse_compare(const Passenger& rhs)
{
  return rhs < *this;    /* Note reverse order! */
}
```

Edit: the above assumes there is a normal `operator <` for Passenger.

[And I'm too slow!]